# Validating Fuzzy Clustering

Tags: r, validation, cluster-analysis

I would like to use fuzzy C-means clustering on a large unsupervided data set of 41 variables and 415 observations. However, I am stuck on trying to validate those clusters. When I plot with a random number of clusters, I can explain a total of 54% of the variance, which is not great and there are no really nice clusters as their would be with the `iris` database for example.

First I ran the `fcm` with my scales data on 3 clusters just to see, but if I am trying to find  way to search for the optimal number of clusters, then I do not want to set an arbitrary defined number of clusters.

So I turned to google and googled: "valdiate fuzzy clustering in R." [This link here was good](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/fuzzy-clustering-essentials/), but I still have to try a bunch of different numbers of clusters. I looked at the `advclust`, `ppclust`, and `clvalid` packages but I could not find a walkthrough for the functions. I looked at the documentation of each package, but also could not discern what to do next.

I walked through some possible number of clusters and checked each one with the `k.crisp` object from fanny. I started with 100 and got down to 4. Based on object description in the documentation,

> k.crisp=integer ( ≤ k ) giving the number of crisp clusters; can be less than 
>   k , where it's recommended to decrease memb.exp.

it doesn't seem like a valid way because it is comparing the number of crisp clusters to our fuzzy clusters.

Is there a function where I can check the validity of my clusters from `2:10` clusters? Also, is it worth while to check the validity of 1 cluster? I think that is a stupid question, but I have a strange feeling 1 optimal cluster might be what I get. (Any tips on what to do if I were to get 1 cluster besides cry a little on the inside?)

**Code**

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(ppclust)
library(advclust)
library(clValid)
data(iris)
df<-sapply(iris[-5],scale)
res.fanny<-fanny(df,3,metric='SqEuclidean')
res.fanny$k.crisp
# When I try to use euclidean, I get the warning all memberships are very close to 1/l. Maybe increase memb.exp, which I don't fully understand
# From my understanding using the SqEuclidean is equivalent to Fuzzy C-means, use the website below. Ultimately I do want to use C-means, hence I use the SqEuclidean distance
fviz_cluster(Res.fanny,ellipse.type='norm',palette='jco',ggtheme=theme_minimal(),legend='right')
fviz_silhouette(res.fanny,palette='jco',ggtheme=theme_minimal())

# With ppclust
set.seed(123)
res.fcm<-fcm(df,centers=3,nstart=10)
```

[website as mentioned above](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.0.7-1/topics/fanny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to go through different number of clusters and see how the percentage of variance explained is changing with different number of clusters. This method is called elbow method.

```
wss <- sapply(2:10, 
       function(k){fcm(df,centers=k,nstart=10)$sumsqrs$tot.within.ss})

plot(2:10, wss,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")
```

The resulting plot is

[image: wss-number of clusters]

After k = 5, total within cluster sum of squares tend to change slowly. So, k = 5 is a good candidate for being optimal number of clusters according to elbow method.

Comment: I am looking more for a formal method. But also isn't that using K-means clustering?

Comment: The objective is similar so I think that we can use this method. Please check this paper, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228407463_A_fuzzy_gap_statistic_for_Fuzzy_C-Means

They are using k = 1 as null hypothesis and use some kind of measure and look for an "elbow" on a graph.